# SQL Replace and where CAST(PromotionRuleData as NVARCHAR(MAX))

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't seem to edit my old post but I am trying to execute this SQL script

```
UPDATE Promotions 
set Description = '£5 Off £25 Spend', 
UsageText = '£5 Off £25 Spend',
EmailText = '£5 Off £25 Spend',
PromotionRuleData= '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="StartDatePromotionRule"><StartDate>2013-11-18T00:00:00</StartDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationDatePromotionRule"><ExpirationDate>2014-01-13T00:00:00</ExpirationDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationNumberOfUsesPerCustomerPromotionRule"><NumberOfUsesAllowed>1</NumberOfUsesAllowed>    </PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="MinimumCartAmountPromotionRule"><CartAmount>24.99</CartAmount></PromotionRuleBase></ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase>',
PromotionDiscountData = '<ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PromotionDiscountBase xsi:type="OrderPromotionDiscount"><DiscountType>Fixed</DiscountType><DiscountAmount>5.00</DiscountAmount></PromotionDiscountBase></ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase>'
where Name = 'test1,test2,etc...'
```

It comes back with this error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I try to use `where CAST(PromotionRuleData as NVARCHAR(MAX))`

So the line reads as

```
CAST(PromotionRuleData as NVARCHAR(MAX)) = '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase ...
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a string literal against a `text` column in SQL Server.

Which column is of datatype `text` ? Your `name` column that you use in the `WHERE` clause by any chance?

If so, use this `WHERE` instead:

```
WHERE CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = 'test1,test2,etc...'
```

or better yet: convert your column to a more appropriate datatype like `VARCHAR(n)` (unless you **really** need 2 GB = 2 billion characters - if so, then use `VARCHAR(MAX)`)

Comment: thanks for the reply getting Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. but understand where you are getting at

Comment: changed the where to like and that executed the script but no records being updated.

Comment: @DeanFraser-Phillips: are you seeing rows returned when you do a `SELECT` on those tables with that `WHERE` clause? If not --> then your `WHERE` clause is fishy and needs to be examined...